# Sony Walkman 3 in 1 and Ubuntu

Tags: 10.04, headphones, sony

I'm considering buying Sony Walkman 3 in 1 (headphones with included MP3 player in them), to be exact the name of model I want to buy is **Sony NWZ-WH303**.

I'm currently running Ubuntu 10.04 and I don't want to buy device which won't work on it. I googled it, but it seems no GNU/Linux user wrote about it yet.

I'd wish it to work simply as a pendrive - plug&play, simply copy the MP3s to the device via USB.

Anyone knows, if it will work like this? Or will I need some fancy apps to transfer the music?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 is no longer supported, please upgrade to a supported release.